# making new data frame from combining text pandas

Tags: python, pandas, hadoop, dataframe, text

I have a pandas data frame that is structured something like this:

```
ID TEXT
1  Start of document
1  middle
1  end of document
2  start of document 2
2  middle
2  end of document 2
```

The raw data I got has repeating IDs which if you concatenate the text for each unique ID you get a resulting document. Some of these IDs repeat hundreds of times resulting in large quantities of text which I would like to boil down to one observation.

I'm not sure how to go about looping through and creating a new document. Also not sure if Pandas is the right data structure to store large quantities of text (these are transcribed call records--some of them 30 minute+ conversations). Would appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC:

```
df.groupby('ID').TEXT.apply(' '.join)

ID
1        Start of document middle end of document
2    start of document 2 middle end of document 2
Name: TEXT, dtype: object
```

Comment: It runs but doesn't seem to do anything: still get repeating IDs with no consolidation. Do you think I need to assign the dataframe to a new variable or have the ID column not be the first column or something?

Comment: @S420L gotta assign returned value back .. `df = df.groupby('ID').TEXT.apply(' '.join)`

Comment: @RafaelC One last question though: do you know what the name of the aggregated column is? My tokenization code no longer works because it can't find the TEXT key

Comment: @RafaelC Assigning to a new column resulted in NaN values so I assigned the resulting series to a new dataframe "df1". From the output of df1.keys() it seems that now each unique ID is a key on the vertical axis. When I print an ID I get the associated text. How might I convert this back into the original form where the IDs are columns and not rows.

Answer (score 2):

If without `groupby`

```
(df.set_index('ID').TEXT+' ').sum(level=0).str[:-1]
Out[1066]: 
ID
1        Start of document middle end of document
2    start of document 2 middle end of document 2
Name: TEXT, dtype: object
```